# Button for database without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, variables, button

i need some help, i have this code on 1st page

```
<?php get_header(); 
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    global $wpdb;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM minipo ORDER BY RAND()");
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $title = $result["title"];
    $name = $result["name"];
?>
```

i need this variabiles:  `$title,  $name` on the 2nd page, with button witch will retrieve again random data from database, without refreshing page. any ideas how i can do that? thx :)

Comment: you can use session to get data in second page.

Comment: How i can do that?

Comment: never ever use mysql_* use mysqli_* or pdo